# Search pattern in text

Tags: python, regex

I have developed this code to find a pattern in a text:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\: (\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})')
match = re.search(pattern, txt)
```

My pattern is a date like this: `dd/mm/yyyy` . The problem is the following: In the text might appear two dates but I want to get just one. The difference between both is the text before the date. I mean:

```
text1: dd/mm/yyyy
text2: dd/mm/yyyy
```

I just want to get the date with the text2 before. How can I do that?

Comment: You always want to get the last one? Or the one with `text2`? It's not entirely clear why you want to pick the second one here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hello mate. Thanks for posting. I want the on with text2, I'll clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: would you please provide sample text in which you are searcing.

Answer (score 3):

Use `text2` in the pattern and capture the date subpattern:

```
import re
txt = """text1: 12/05/2015
text2: 22/05/2016"""
pattern = re.compile(r'text2:\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})')
match = re.search(pattern, txt)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XgmiDF)

**Details**:

- `text2:` -  a literal substring
- `\s*` -  0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` - capturing group 1 that matches 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/` and then 4 digits.

The `re.search` method will find the first match, and if found, we need to get the contents of the first capturing group (`match.group(1)`).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could put every date you find in list, and then take the last one.

```
list_of_dates = []
pattern = re.compile(r'\: (\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}))') 

for date in pattern.finditer(txt):
   list_of_dates.append(date.group(1)) # Take date as back reference

list_of_dates[-1] # This would give you last date
```

Comment: This won't work if the date with the text2 before is not the last one in the string.

Comment: Yes, but does she know what text2 is? I Understood text2 come after text1.

Comment: @AleksandarMakragić Thanks for your help and sorry for the misunderstanding. I know what text2 is and it doesn't have anything to do with the position.

Comment: Np :) You should just prepend text2 to regex then like @WiktorStribiżew explained.